# Can VBScript be used for public websites?

Tags: vbscript

I have piece of VBScript and I want to use it on my website.
I believe that VBScript can only work on **IE**
but my question is can VBScript work for people that not on my intranet?
For example if www.stackoverflow.com has a function written in VBScript, would the function be able to be executed by its visitors and without any security limitation or only for computers that on the local stackoverflow network?

Answer (score 1):

Using VBScript on a public site is fine, so long as you are willing to accept that it will only run for those using IE.

The reason it is not commonly used is exactly because it will only run on IE. Most developers want their code to run on as many browsers as possible, so they use javascript.

In general, I would suggest not to use VBScript on the client side.

Answer (score 0):

VBScript is not used by StackOverflow, the fact that it works only in IE, it should be avoided, use ***Javascript*** instead.

Comment: I think he provided StackOverflow as a fictitious example. It's possible to use VBScript as an aid to Javascript. Any functions declared in VBScript are available to Javascript scripts. Agreed that it should be avoided in general, but it can be used to provide helper functions to IE using methods like `execScript`. I've used techniques like this before, albeit in IE-only applications.

Comment: @Andy E's head: Agreed and that is interesting indeed to use it for IE-specific stuff something I had never considered before but in the future i will for sure. Thanks